# Find all printer models in INF file - VB.NET - Combobox

Tags: vb.net

I have been using Visual Basic and Visual Studio to create a nice GUI with severals tools for the print tech guys here. In this tool I would like the technicans to choose the correct .inf files and the populate a combobox with all the printer models listed in the file.

I know how to allow them to choose the file, but I do not know how to make the Visual Basic program read out the printer models. 
In the inf files there could be several models listed like this:

```
;WindowsXP(amd64)
[Gestetner.NTamd64]
"Gestetner MP C3002 PCL 6"
"Gestetner MP C3502 PCL 6"

[infotec.NTamd64]
"infotec MP C3002 PCL 6"
"infotec MP C3502 PCL 6"
```

Do you know how I can read out all the lines and then populate a combobox with only the printer models? Without the quotes of course.

In Powershell i do this by sending the code below, but I don't understand how I get the same result in vb.

```
$Regex = Get-Content $InfPath\*.inf | Select-String -Pattern '"[A-z0-9 ]{1,}"'

Foreach ($Lines in $Regex)
{
$Lines = $Lines.Line.Split("""")[1]
$Lines | Format-List
}
```

Comment: do i have an eye problem your code is in really `c#` ?

Comment: Hehe, the code pasted at the end is showing how I did it in Powershell. Thought maybe it made it easier to show what I was after. The other gray area at the top is the .inf file.

Comment: oh okay...so u want a vb.net solution,right ?

Comment: Yes please! I am not very good at coding and vb.net and powershell is the only two I have been working with.

Comment: do u want to read the files and add items to the combobox from the files ?

Comment: The short answer to that is yes.

The long answer is also yes, I would like to populate the combobox with the printer models it finds in the .inf files. The printer models are listed inside the quotes as you can see in the question. There can be several printer models in each .inf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment you made to @zach raiyan's answer this is the code that you need:

```
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FilePathHere).Where(Function(l1) l1.Contains("""")).Select(Function(l) l.Split("""")(1)).ToArray())
```

Comment: This Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want :( .But i assume you want to read data from a file and add items to a combobox accordingly ,right ?
For that,do this :

```
 ComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FilePathHere)
```

or u can split the text if required :

```
  ComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FilePathHere).Select(Function(l) l.Split("""")(1)).ToArray())
```

Comment: It might be my english that makes it unclear what I want. I am very sorry about that. 

Anyway, this is not exactly what I am looking for since this will add all the lines in the file into the Combobox. What I really want is to just add the text between the quotes. So if the line read "Gestetner MP C3002 PCL 6" then I would like to add Gestetner MP C3002 PCL 6 to the combobox.